# Facebook apprequests notification doesn't redirect user to app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I'm developing an Android app and
trying to put a button to send app install requests to facebook friends.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "apprequest");
params.putString("message", "App Invitation");
WebDialog dialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(), Session.getActiveSession(), params).build();
dialog.show();
```

The code above works fine. When the code executes, the notification is delivered to friend successfully.

After that, the problem occurs.
On Android devices, when user clicks the notification on Facebook app, the Facebook app redirects user to my app's Facebook Page.

However, on iPhone, when user clicks the notification on Facebook app, the Facebook app redirects user to my app or App Store.

Why different behavior?
I want the behavior of iPhone side. What should I fix ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you turned on deep linking for your android app in the FB app settings?

Comment: getting same problem, and yes I turned on deep linking with all the above steps, but redirection to android app from notification is not happening, need help....

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Deep Linking for your app in your App's facebook page. It should be under the Native Android App section.

Also make sure Sandbox mode is disabled though it probably is if the notification went through. :-)

Hope that helps!